# Unable to autowire sessionfactory object in hibernate utility class,though i am getting it on controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bizega.bzcrm" />

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />


<!--    <bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>-->

<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!--     Hibernate SessionFactory  -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bizega.bzcrm.hbmapping"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateUtil" class="com.bizega.bzcrm.util.HibernateUtil">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

this is my dispathureservlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd"/>
```

this is my aaplicationContext.xml

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

EmployeeService empService = new EmployeeService();

@RequestMapping(value = "/{menuid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<ModuleWrapper>> getModule(@PathVariable int menuid) throws Exception {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(empService.getModule(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save.lx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createEmployee(@ModelAttribute EmployeeFormBean employee, ModelMap obj) {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("sf", sessionFactory);
    Employee employee1 = new Employee();
    employee1.setDesgid(employee.getDesigid());
    employee1.setEmpcode(employee.getEmpcode());
    employee1.setMobile(employee.getMobile());
    employee1.setEmpname(employee.getName());
    employee1.setAhid(1);
    employee1.setDeptid(1);
    employee1.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
    employee1.setPhone(employee.getPhone());
    employee1.setIsactive(1);
    empService.saveEmployee(employee1, map);
    List<Employee> employees = empService.findAllEmployees(map);
    obj.addAttribute("employees", employees);

    return "userlist";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteuser.lx", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteEmployee(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap obj) {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("sf", sessionFactory);
    empService.deleteEmployeeById(id, map);
    List<Employee> employees = empService.findAllEmployees(map);
    obj.addAttribute("employees", employees);
    return "userlist";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/edituser.lx", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String updateEmployee(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap obj)  {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("sf", sessionFactory);
    Employee emp = empService.findById(id, map);
    obj.addAttribute("employee", emp);
    return "updateEmp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update.lx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateEmployeeDetails(@ModelAttribute Employee employee, ModelMap obj) {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("sf", sessionFactory);
    empService.updateEmployee(employee, map);
    List<Employee> employees = empService.findAllEmployees(map);
    obj.addAttribute("employees", employees);
    return "userlist";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/listEmp.lx")
public String listEmployee(ModelMap obj) {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("sf", sessionFactory);
    List<Employee> employees = empService.findAllEmployees(map);
    obj.addAttribute("employees", employees);
    return "userlist";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEmpField.lx")
public String updateSingleField(@RequestBody SingleField singleField)    {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("sf", sessionFactory);
    empService.updateEmpField(singleField,map);
   // obj.addAttribute("employees", employees);
    return "userlist";
}

}
```

this is my controller

```
@Transactional
@Service("empService")
public class EmployeeService {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

EmployeeDataManager datamanager = new EmployeeDataManager();

public List<ModuleWrapper> getModule() throws Exception {
    return datamanager.getModule();
}

@Transactional
public void saveEmployee(Employee employee, Map map) {
    datamanager.saveEmployee(employee, map);
}

public List<Employee> findAllEmployees(Map map) {
    return datamanager.findAllEmployees(map);
}

public void deleteEmployeeById(int id, Map map) {
    datamanager.deleteEmployeeById(id, map);
}

public Employee findById(int id, Map map) {
    return datamanager.findById(id, map);
}

public void updateEmployee(Employee employee, Map map) {
    datamanager.updateEmployee(employee, map);
}

public void updateEmpField(SingleField singleField,Map map)
{
    datamanager.updateEmpField(singleField,map);
}

}
```

this is my service

```
@Transactional
@Component
public class EmployeeDataManager extends HibernateUtil {
private HibernateUtil hbutil;

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public void saveEmployee(final Employee employee, Map map) {
    hbutil = new HibernateUtil();
    hbutil.save(employee, map);
}

public List<Employee> findAllEmployees(Map map) {
    hbutil = new HibernateUtil();
    hbutil.test();
    return hbutil.getAll(Employee.class, map);
}

public void deleteEmployeeById(int id, Map map) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) map.get("sf");
    Employee employee = hbutil.get(Employee.class, id, map);
    hbutil.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    hbutil.delete(employee, map);
}

public Employee findById(int id, Map map) {
    hbutil = new HibernateUtil();
    Employee employee = hbutil.get(Employee.class, id, map);
    return employee;
}

public void updateEmployee(Employee employee, Map map) {
    hbutil = new HibernateUtil();
    Employee e1 = hbutil.get(Employee.class, employee.getEmpid(), map);
    e1.setEmpname(employee.getEmpname());
    e1.setDesgid(employee.getDesgid());
    e1.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
    e1.setEmpcode(employee.getEmpcode());
    e1.setMobile(employee.getMobile());
    e1.setPhone(employee.getPhone());
    //  e1.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
    hbutil.saveOrUpdate(e1);
}

}
```

this is my data manager

```
@Transactional
@Component
public class HibernateUtil {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public <T> T save(final T o, Map map) {
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) map.get("sf");
    return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(o);
}

public void delete(final Object object, Map map) {
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) map.get("sf");
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(object);
}

/**
 *
 * @param <T>
 * @param type
 * @param id
 * @param map
 * @return
 */
public <T> T get(final Class<T> type, final int id, Map map) {
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) map.get("sf");
    return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(type, id);
}


public <T> T merge(final T o) {
    return (T) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(o);
}
/**
 *
 *
 * @param <T>
 * @param o
 */
public <T> void saveOrUpdate(final T o) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(o);
}

public <T> List<T> getAll(final Class<T> type, Map map) {
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) map.get("sf");
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    final Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(type);
    return crit.list();
}

public <T> void updateSingleField(final Class<T> type, SingleField singleField, Map map) {
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) map.get("sf");
    final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("update " + type.getSimpleName() + " set " + singleField.getColName() + "=:newValue where id=:id");
    query.setParameter("newValue", singleField.getNewValue());
    query.setParameter("id", singleField.getId());
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("dfdfds   " + sessionFactory);
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}
}
```

this is my hibernateUtil class

I am getting sessionfactory object at controller but not getting it in my datamanager and hibernate util so i have topass it using map

i am totally new to spring so please help me to solve this problem where i am wrong if you want any other details let me know

thanks in advance

Comment: Remove all the new instance creation. You are creating instances yourself (of the service, manager and util) don't let spring inject those.

Comment: is it relate with sessionFactory Autowiring?

Comment: thanks bro it help a lot issue sortout

Answer (score 0):

To get bean with autowired fields you have to get it from applicationcontext, e.g. autowiring it. Spring is not so magical to inject beans to you object created by yourself with just "new Myobject()"

Comment: i get it in my controller so whats wrong with my HibernateUtil

Comment: nothing is wrong with HibernateUtil. What's wrong is how you instantiate it